# Why I cannot split a string by "\\003" or "\\x03" correctly in Scala?

Tags: python, scala

I hava a string which is concat by "0x03", when I use Python to split it, I got an array of length 42, which is correctly. But when I tried to use Scala to split it, the length of array that I got is 36. I tried "\003", "\x03", "\u0003" and something like that, but still cannot split it correctly. Why this happen? Scala cannot recognize this character?
Like below, the `line` is a string that I read from a `txt` file.

in Scala, I got 36, which is wrong

```
val a = line.split("\u0003").length
println(a)
```

but in Python, I got 42, which is right

```
a = len(line.split('\003'))
print(a)
```

this is my example input

```
1000000481  134钦州市浦北|431.25129612936434.4564367432625549334.2483209223432662162883.721353081623956970011.94590494644300403.21917874189wxc4c0253df149f02d4wxc4c0253df149f02d2wxc4c0253df149f02d2wxc4c0253df149f02d2wxc4c0253df149f02d3wxc4c0253df149f02d3wxc4c0253df149f02d2wxc4c0253df149f02d2wxc4c0253df149f02d2wxc4c0253df149f02d2鲁班七号后羿程咬金夏侯惇亚瑟壁纸1.164墙贴1.164正面62段子37侧面33汽车23绘画23搞笑22电影黑条20烹饪教程16室内15听书14游戏13食物12工厂12挖掘机11乡村11天空8家居8农村8旅游景点8书法8王者荣耀29QQ音乐16和平精英13酷狗音乐216208.07598472.375111588.07598522.375119658.07598872.375foojo4.75墨斗鱼2.85百目源（BAIMUYUANN）1.910000018775.710001043212.856148901.9
```

Comment: hey man, if u think this is a bad and very easy question, please answer or commit it, instead of  just cast opposing votes

Comment: Well... can you show the code snippet which is causing this issue ?

Comment: thank u , I add some code

Comment: Its missing sample input and expected output. Just add scala code for creating your sample input.

Comment: What happens if you do it on a test string like `"a\x03b\x03c\x03d"`?

Comment: It seems that "a\x03b\x03c\x03d" cannot used as a string is Scala

Comment: @chong You can not write `val s = "a\x03b\x03c\x03d"`. As `'\'` is the escape character in Java/Scala strings. You will have do eiher tell scala that this is a raw string by `val s = raw"a\x03b\x03c\x03d"` or escape the escape character by `val s = "a\\x03b\\x03c\\x03d"`

Comment: @ Sarvesh Kumar Singh then how to split this val s = "a\\x03b\\x03c\\x03d" in Scala?

Comment: @chong So this is supposed to be unicode character ?

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh Sorry I am not familiar with these things, maybe it is unicode character. Why cannot I split this string by ''\u0003"

Comment: It's not the split that's the problem. It's something to do with how you're constructing or processing the string. We need to see that code to be able to help.

Comment: See... if you want to split the string by unicde `0003` (which is `?` character) then you can just do `s.split('\u0003')`.

Comment: I do not have the code that processing those strings, someone others write those code. The only thing they told me is that those strings can be split by '/003' in Python

Comment: @chong Provide a smaller string (with how you are defining it in Scala) and your expected output.

Comment: Why not analyze/compare the good (Python) results with the bad (Scala) results? Then you could _describe_ what you want and what you're getting, and you could prepare a **small** and easy-to-replicate example _demonstrating_ the problem.

Comment: The ineresting this is that the string input has only one character which occurs 40 times (and thus can possibly result in a split size of 42) and that character is exactly `3`. And if I try `len(line.split('\003'))` in python for OP's input I am getting `1`. This means that there are a lot of problems with the information provided by OP.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? If it's python 2, then I believe your split will look for bytes with the value `3` and split them there.  Depending on the unicode encoding of the file, this could result in splitting in the middle of a multi-byte character instead of splitting on Unicode character 3.